# How do we write an `except` statement which catches nothing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, try-catch

I want a `try`-block such that ***any*** exception raised inside of the`try`-block goes unhandled. This is so that I can write a try block in preparation for the future. Some day, I will write in some meaningful error handling. However, I don't have real `except` statements yet.  The following sort of works, but is ugly

```
_ = type("", (Exception,), dict())

try:
    lizard = [1, 2, 3]
    y = z + w
    print(lizard[983])
except _:
    print("I hope this string never prints")
```

Comment: You can write `except Exception:` without defining a poorly-named subclass of `Exception`.

Comment: @chepner But then ***every*** exception would be caught. I want the opposite: I want ***zero*** exceptions to be caught.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Skip the `except` clause altogether. A `try` statement needs at least one `except` clause *or* a `finally` clause, which executes whether or not you catch an exception.

```
try:
    lizard = [1, 2, 3]
    y = z + w
    print(lizard[983])
finally:
    pass
```

The `finally` clause won't actually execute any code, and does not affect the control flow of your code in any way; it just injects a no-op before you leave the `try` statement, whether by successfully completing the code or by raising an uncaught exception.

Once you start adding `except` clauses, you can either remove the `finally` clause or leave it in place.

(A deleted answer catches and immediately reraises any exception, which is also fine IMO:

```
try:
    ...
except Exception:
    raise
```

)

Comment: It is strange that answer with reraising was removed. It looks more close to the point that some day OP will change the `raise` statement into useful handling.

Answer (score 0):

```
try:
   # do something
except:
   pass   # this will make nothing
```

the pass keyword is used for that purpose. when you want to make nothing, just write some code and come back later and think about what you really want to do there (or at least that's how I use it)

Comment: This handles *every* exception by ignoring it, rather than leaving every exception unhandled.

Comment: @chepner I know. I answered based on the question. he wanted a way to ignore (let it unhandled) and someday he will come back and write some meaningful handling. I would use the pass keyword for the Task. I use it also when I create classes and functions just as a temporary ignoring keyword, later I would change it.

Comment: It's *not* unhandled. You caught it, and said it's fine by not doing anything about it.

Comment: @basilisk The desired behavior is that an ugly error message appear on the console, and the program stops running. For your solution, when exception is raised, the program keeps running, and no ugly error message appears.